# is dynamic change of css class on svg text taken into account?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I was changing an svg text from bold to normal, and back, with no problem. like :

```
if ( boldyze_it ){
document.getElementById(zz).style.fontWeight = "bold";
}else{
document.getElementById(zz).style.fontWeight = "normal";
}
```

I wished to have a full style change, thus changing the css class. like that:

```
if ( boldyze_it ){
document.getElementById(zz).className = "emphit";
}else{
document.getElementById(zz).className = "clear";
}
```

and some css declartions, like :

```
.emphit {
    font-weight : bold;
}

.clear{
    font-weight : normal;
}
```

but now, I get no effect. did I messed up with something, or is it just that dynamic change of css class does not apply to svg in my browser ?

tanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className` is an HTML DOM property.  It won't work with SVGs.  Use `setAttribute()` instead:

```
if ( boldyze_it ){
   document.getElementById("zz").setAttribute("class", "emphit");
}else{
   document.getElementById("zz").setAttribute("class", "clear");
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sEf9E/)